# Excel custom data validation that restricts entry to date or "NA"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, validation

I am working on a training tracker for over 250 staff and over 100 training modules. I need  to restrict entries into cells to only dates (in format dd/mm/yyyy) greater than the training version date (contained in cell C10) and smaller or equal to the actual date of imput or "N/A" if there is no training requirement. I would apprecite formula suggestions which would not require changing cell format to text.
I've tried the following formula in custom validation: =OR(C11="N/A",NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(C11))) but it requires changing cell format to text and does not restrict date range

Comment: What have you tried so far? Excel has validation and entry restriction capabilities built-in. Have you attempted to implement these?

Comment: I've tried the following formula in custom validation: =OR(C11="N/A",NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(C11))) but it requires changing cell format to text and does not restrict date range

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to any and all additional information to the question itself. This helps improve the question until the solution is clear and found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Select the Data Range you want to apply Validation and write this formula as Custom Rule.*

```
=OR(C241=$D$236,AND(C241>$D$237, C241<=$D$238))
```

- C241 is the first Cell of the Range.
- Cell D236 has value NA.
- Cell D237 has Training Version Date.
- D238 has Input Date.

*Adjust the cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks Rajesh S. I was trying to avoid having extra cells with data to refer to in the formula but this solution definitely addresses all requirements. Might just have to hide and lock the cells with NA and Input date.

Comment: @Boyarskee, Glad  to help you,, keep asking ☺

Comment: upvoted but since I'm a new user it doesn't show on publicly displayed post score. Thanks again!

Comment: @Boyarskee, if you check my profile page (Hit my picture), you find Score of each Answer left to it posted by me, including this one ! ☺

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in Data Validation:

[image]

I believe the `mm/dd/yyyy` will work by default, assuming your regional settings are as such. (I.e. you're not in the UK, or somewhere where `dd/mm/yyyy` or some other is the default format).

For the `N/A`, what determines that?  That's the only small bit I don't have accounted for.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne. Being able to input N/A when training is not required acording to training matrix is very important. That is why I am looking for a formula to allow custom validation.

Comment: @Boyarskee how/where in the spreadsheet would you know if it's not applicable? If C11 says so?

Comment: training matrix is a separate workbook.  It specifies what training is required according to department and role. After checking the matrix the user knows what training is required and then needs to input either valid date of training or N/A in the correct cell in the training tracker.

Comment: Each training module has a different version date, e.g. C10 for module1, D10 for module2, E10 for mofule 3 etc. User will learn from the matrix that they need to do module 1, 3 and 5 and then they need to input valid dates in columns C, E and G and input N/A in columns D and F.